# Python lint rule to avoid single-value parentheses without a trailing comma

Tags: python, tuples, lint, pylint, parentheses

## My Problem

A friend of mine recently [tweeted](https://twitter.com/GadiAleks/status/1209053985711235072) (Hebrew) about an annoying Pythonic bug caused by a missing comma:

[image]

The values for the `F0`-`F2` keys are tuples, while the value of the `F3` key is a string. This happens because the trailing comma inside the parentheses marks their content as a single-value tuple.

I think that parentheses with a single value make little sense, and they should be marked as a style or lint error.

## My Question

**Is there a Pythonic lint rule that forbids parentheses with a single literal or object and no trailing comma?**

Comment: Such a rule would prohibit all parentheses that are redundant with precedence—is that OK?

Comment: If they contain a single literal - yes.

Comment: That’s a slightly different question, but sounds reasonable.

Comment: Type hints could be used to specify that the dictionary's values ought to be tuples or str, if your friend is open to using type hints.